# Проблема с установкой oracledb для nodejs в RH4.4

Tags: node.js, oracle, install

Не собирается nodejs oracledb в Red Hat 4.4.7. Та же последовательность действий в Centos7 нормально срабатывает.
Делаю так:

```
yum install libaio gcc-c++
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/oracle/instantclient_12_1
export OCI_LIB_DIR=/usr/local/oracle/instantclient_12_1
OCI_INC_DIR=/usr/local/oracle/instantclient_12_1/sdk/include
npm i oracledb --python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7
```

В результате получаю:

```
....
gyp ERR! build error 
gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/root/.nvm/v4.7.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:211:12)
gyp ERR! System Linux 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
gyp ERR! command "/root/.nvm/v4.7.3/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/v4.7.3/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /var/hiv/node_modules/oracledb
gyp ERR! node -v v4.7.3
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.4.0
gyp ERR! not ok 
npm ERR! Linux 2.6.32-431.el6.x86_64
npm ERR! argv "/root/.nvm/v4.7.3/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/v4.7.3/bin/npm" "i" "oracledb" "--python=/usr/local/bin/python2.7"
npm ERR! node v4.7.3
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.11
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

npm ERR! oracledb@1.12.2 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the oracledb@1.12.2 install script 'node-gyp rebuild'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the oracledb package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-gyp rebuild
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs oracledb
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR! 
npm ERR!     npm owner ls oracledb
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /var/hiv/npm-debug.log
```

Никто не сталкивался с такой проблемой?

Answer (score 0):

День убил на эту проблему, ответ нашелся сам-собой, как только запостил вопрос:)

В RH, оказывается, нужно вручную указывать пути к компилляторам:

```
env CC=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/gcc CXX=/opt/rh/devtoolset-2/root/usr/bin/g++ npm install oracledb
```

Проблема решена, надеюсь...